# Getting selected text with cross frame scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, dom, xss

I've been struggling with a problem for a few hours now, and I would appreciate either some help in accomplishing my goal, or confirmation that what I'm trying to do is in fact impossible.

I have a webapp that takes the selected text (`document.getSelection()`) as input, from an arbitrary webpage. While it would be possible to use a bookmarklet to do such scripting fairly easily, it's best for the end-user if I can accomplish this with an iframe.

The parent frame is my site with this script:

```
$('#frame').load(function(){
    // this event won't be triggered
    $(window).mouseup(function(){
        doStuff(window.getSelection()); 
    });

    // this will throw a security error
    $(window.frames[0].document).mouseup(function(){
        doStuff(window.frames[0].document.getSelection()); 
    });                  
});
```

An arbitrary site is in the child frame. Unless the child document is from my domain, access is forbidden for XSS security reasons. I've tried several variations and attempted hacks, including setting the iframe `src` to my domain with the third party URL as an argument, and then redirecting to the third party URL. In a sense, I'm glad that it didn't work (because if it did, then `XSS` security would still have a long way to go...)

Another option would be downloading the third party page and serving it from my domain like a proxy server, but I've already run into a bunch of problems with relative paths to files, which are sometimes easy to make absolute, but sometimes a fool's errand (such as when the files are accessed via script).

I've concluded that I might just be out of luck. Perhaps an important distinction for my case is that I only want to access the `.getSelection()` method for the child. No need to be able to access cookies or keystrokes or interact with the DOM. Maybe it doesn't make a difference, but maybe it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the proxy method but insert a [base](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag that points to the original domain. The paths should be taken care of then.

I wouldn't rely on any XSS hacks even if you could find them -- they'd likely be corrected and most likely not crossbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is to write your iframe's document with text from an XHR, or use jQuery's `load()` function, this only works if there is no navigation in the iframe though.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully read your answer :-) but maybe I have a solution,
it involves passing data between parent and child frames, both ways.

You can WRITE (and not READ) the hash (hash is the http://url#HASH_PART) of parent from child.
So, on the parent iframe, just set interval to check the value, say every 50ms.

```
function checkHash() {
    if (window.location.hash == "#something") {
        // my child frame set this value using: 
        //parent.window.location.hash = "something";
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

For further details, and maybe doing parent to child communications, then 
the full article explaining this (also has demo link) can be found [here](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).